# How can I use glass.arff as a neo4j database?

Tags: neo4j, weka

I use glass.arff dataset in Java to apply Weka classes and I need to use Louvain algorithm to select the features. I want to use Louvain algorithm in the neo4j package. How can I use glass.arff as a neo4j database?

Answer (score 0):

What would your graph model for the dataset look like? 
Could you explain in more detail what you want to do?

Basically you would load the CSV and create nodes and relationships from it

```
UNWIND ['build wind float', 'build wind non-float', 'vehic wind float', 'vehic wind non-float', 'containers', 'tableware', 'headlamps'] as type 
CREATE (g:Glass {type:type});

LOAD CSV FROM "http://www.sc.ehu.es/ccwbayes/docencia/mmcc/files/UCI-MMCC/glass.arff" AS row
CREATE (o:Observation {RI:row[0],Na:row[1],Mg:row[2],Al:row[3],Si:row[4],K:row[5],Ca:row[6],Ba:row[7],Fe:row[8],Type:row[9]})
MATCH (g:Glass {type:row[9]})
CREAT (o)-[:TYPE]->(g);
```

Comment: Thank you,I'm new. 
I want to use the Louvain algorithm for feature clustering , and then, based on these clusters, I will apply a feature selection method, and finally, I will classify it using a classification method in Weka.